# How to remove points from a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot.

I would like to do the following:

1. I want to plot a series of ***background*** dots (single blue dot in
   example).
2. I add an ***additional*** series of dots (3 black dots in example)
3. I save the figure
4. I remove the ***additional*** series of dots (black) and keep the ***background*** one (blue).

How can I perform step 4? I would like to avoid having to replot the background dots.

Hereunder is an example of code with step 4 missing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.ylim(-10,10)

#step 1: background blue dot
plt.plot(0,0,marker='o',color='b')

#step 2: additional black dots
points_list = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
for point in points_list:
    plt.plot(point[0],point[1],marker='o',color='k')

#step 3: save
plt.savefig('test.eps')

#step 4: remove additional black dots
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) function returns a list of [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) objects which represent the plotted data. These objects have a [`remove`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove.html) method which will remove them from the figure they've been plotted on (note that `Line2D` inherits from `Artist` which you can check via `Line2D.__mro__`):

```
remove() method of matplotlib.lines.Line2D instance
    Remove the artist from the figure if possible.  The effect
    will not be visible until the figure is redrawn, e.g., with
    :meth:`matplotlib.axes.Axes.draw_idle`.  Call
    :meth:`matplotlib.axes.Axes.relim` to update the axes limits
    if desired.

    [...]
```

So you can do the following (I combined plotting the single points in one go):

```
points = plt.plot(*zip(*points_list), 'o', color='k')[0]
# Remove the points (requires redrawing).
points.remove()
```

Keeping your `for` loop this would be:

```
points = []
for point in points_list:
    points.extend(
        plt.plot(point[0], point[1], marker='o', color='k')
    )
for p in points:
    p.remove()
```

Or more concise using a list comprehension:

```
points = [plt.plot(*p, marker='o', color='k')[0] for p in points_list]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the plotted points by doing this :

```
temporaryPoints, = plt.plot(point[0],point[1],marker='o',color='k')
temporaryPoints.remove()
```

Comment: thanks, it works just fine if I add a comma after 'temporaryPoints' on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#step 2
black_points, = plt.plot( zip(*points_list), marker="o", color="k")

#... step 3 ...
#...

#step 4
black_points.set_visible( False)
```